# Can't add to a string literal in C to shift its index

Tags: c, string, indexing, constants

I was code-golfing the famous "fizzbuzz" screening question in C (The point of this question is understanding how C operators work, not code golf; don't vote me off topic ^^"), and I came up with this line:

```
puts(&"Fizz\0FizzBuzz"[i%15?i%3?9:0:5]));
```

Which seems a little unnecessary to me because I thought I could just do:

```
puts("Fizz\0FizzBuzz"+i%15?i%3?9:0:5));
```

but that segfaults on the first would-be `Fizz`. My question is: why can't I index a string literal by simply adding to it? I've tried casting the addend to `size_t`, but that does nothing useful. Given that for an arbitrary `char *p` (or a pointer to any type for that matter), `p[n]`is just syntactic sugar for `(*p+n)`, and (I think) `&*p == p.`

Why, then, is `&p[n] != p+n`?

**EDIT:** Turns out I was just catching `Fizz\0FizzBuzz"+i%15` in my `?:`. Damned operator precedence. I'm a moron. :)

Comment: What is the precedence of the ?: operator? (See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) for a hint.)

Comment: Oh jeez, I messed up on conditional operator precedence... I feel stupid. Do I delete this question now?

Comment: Up to you. Someone might get a chuckle out of it if you don't.

Comment: Fair enough. May as well edit my OP to reflect my epiphany.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem your code is that you are missing parentheses. This works perfectly fine:

```
puts("Fizz\0FizzBuzz"+(i%15?i%3?9:0:5));
```

In your original code the condition of the first `?` `:` operator is

```
"Fizz\0FizzBuzz"+i%15
```

which is not what you intended.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/kKhixE)